# OpenCL: Store pointer to global memory in local memory?

Tags: c, opencl, gpgpu

any solutions?

Is that even possible?

```
__global *float abc; // pointer to global memory stored in private memory
```

I want abc to be stored **in local memory** instead of private memory.

Comment: abc is an address of some storage in global memory.   Typically its stored in a register. Do you what to hold this address in a local? Why? Or do you want to copy the data  at address abc to local storage? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, you got it right: I want to hold this address (abc) in local memory. Why? Maybe to be able to access it from other threads?! (That's what local memory is for, isn't it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is clarified [here](http://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/opencl-c/) List 5.2:

```
__global int global_data[128];  // 128 integers allocated on global memory
__local float *lf;  // pointer placed on the private memory, which points to a single-precision float located on the local memory
__global char * __local lgc[8];  // 8 pointers stored on the local memory that points to a char located on the global memory
```

As I understand for pointers: [where they point] type * [where to store] name;

Comment: Haven't verified this but thanks for the reference! This is now the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have also encountered a similar problem as you before, as I explored, I think it works in such a way: in OpenCL kernel, variables inside a kernel without an address qualifier (__local, __global, etc) will be automatically considered to be stored in __private memory space. For pointers which are not declared with space qualifier, it will also be considered to point to __private space. Here is an example code snippet:

```
__kernel void foo(__global uint *ptr)
{
    uint tid = get_global_id(0);
    uint * localPtr = ptr;
    uint   var= *(localPtr + tid);
    ... ...
}
```

In the above code snippet, the localPtr is an uint type pointer which has no memory space qualifier, so it will be automatically considered to point to _*private memory space. In OpenCL, a pointer to address space A (*_global, for example) can only be assigned to a pointer to the same address space (__global). So in the above example, a pointer to __private address space cannot be assigned with a pointer (ptr) which points to __global address. (For this point, you can also refer to OpenCL Spec in the section "Address Space Qualifiers"). Hope this can be helpful!

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not answering my question, but thanks anyway. :) (Your description is correct, though)

Answer (score 0):

This is legal:

```
global uint *globalPtr=&ptr[tid]
```