# OpenCL Pointer to Local Memory in Local Memory as Function Argument?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I want to pass the local memory declared in my kernel function to another function for some processing.  I would like to control it so that all my pointers are declared in local space as well:

```
void funcB(__local float * __local p)
{
}

__kernel void funcA()
{
    __local float data[256];
    __local float * __local ptr;
    ptr = data;
    funcB(ptr);
}
```

and funcB declaration does not work because:
    error: parameter may not be qualified with an address space

Is there a way to do something like this?  Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978024/opencl-store-pointer-to-global-memory-in-local-memory

Comment: That post is on the right track but makes no mention of its usage as a function argument.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OpenCL Spec 1.2 section 6.5.4:

> all variables inside non-kernel functions, and all function arguments are in the __private or private address space.

As the non-kernel functions are inlinded so I am not sure what you would want to accomplish by doing this anyway.

Comment: That seems to be the answer.  Thanks.